# Input type file not serialize jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serialization

I want to send form data using ajax done by serialize method but input type text and email is serialized in array but input type file not serialize in array

```
<form role="form" action="javascript:;" id="myform"  enctype = "multipart/form-data" method = "post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Photo:</label>
          <input type="file" name="userPhoto"  id="userPhoto" class="form-control"  />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit_add" id="enter">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

**And Ajax Code**

```
$('.submit_add').click(function(e){ 
          e.preventDefault();
          var data = $('#myform').serialize();

          console.log(data); return false;
          $.ajax({ 
              url: '/ajax',
              type: 'POST',
              cache: false, 
              data: data,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data) {
                          if (data.success == true ) {
                            window.location.href  = '/';
                          } else {
                            alert('Error : There is something wrong.');
                          }
                        },
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
                   alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err);
               }
          })
      });
```

**Console response**

**name=manish+prajapati&email=kumar%40manish.com**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I serialize file type input in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913562/how-do-i-serialize-file-type-input-in-jquery)

Answer (score 14):

You should try this:

```
var data = new FormData($("#myform")[0]);
```

and set:

```
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```

See more here: http://portfolio.planetjon.ca/2014/01/26/submit-file-input-via-ajax-jquery-easy-way/

Answer (score 0):

I use jquery (but this can be easily done via vanilla javascript too) to create a hidden text input after the file input. I then set the name of the new text input as the id of the file input it's associated with and set it's value (when a file is selected) to the filename. You can then use $('form').serializeArray(); and return the name:value pairs of the hidden inputs that correspond to the file inputs.

```js
/* The javascript/jquery */

$(document).ready(function(){

  // Dynamically create hidden text inputs for the file inputs' data
  // (create dynamically to avoid having re-write your entire html file)
 $('input:file').each( function(){
    $(this).after('<input type="text" readonly name="' + $(this).attr("id").replace("_", " ") + '" hidden value=""/>');
  });
  
  
  // When the user selects a file to be uploaded...
  $('input:file').change( function(){
  
    // If a file is selected set the text input value as the filename
    if($(this).get(0).files.length !== 0){
      $(this).next('input:text').val($(this).get(0).files[0].name);
    }
  
  });
  
  
  $("form").submit( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //Clear previous data from results div
    $('#results').text("");
    
    // Serialize the form data
    var x = $('form').serializeArray();
    
    // Iterate through the array results and append
    // the data to the results div
    $.each(x, function(i, field) {
      var result  = '<span class="left">' + field.name + ' : </span>';
          result += '<span class="right">' + field.value + '</span><br>';
      $('#results').append(result);
    });
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
/* The .css */

form {
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0; 
  width: auto;
  max-width: 40%;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div.left, div.right, span.left, span.right { 
  display:block; 
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
}
.rad { font-size: 14px; }
.left { float: left; }
.right { float: right; }

#results { 
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 40%; 
  line-height: 23px;
}
#results .left { 
  color: green; 
  text-align: right;
}
#results .right { 
  color: blue; 
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.clearfix { clear: both; }
```

```html
<!-- The HTML -->

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <div class="left">
      <label class="right" for="name">Name:</label><br>
      <label class="right" for="gender">Gender:</label><br>
      <label class="right" for="file1">1st Pic:</label><br>
      <label class="right" for="file2">2nd Pic:</label><br>
      <label class="right" for="file3">3rd Pic:</label><br>
      <label class="right" for="file4">4th Pic:</label><br>
    </div>
    
    <div class="right">
      <input class="left" type="text" name="Name" ><br>
      <select class="left" name="Gender">
        <option selected></option>
        <option>Unspecified</option>
        <option>Female</option>
        <option>Male</option>
      </select><br>
      
      <input class="left" type="file" accept="image/*" id="File_1"><br>
      <input class="left" type="file" accept="image/*" id="File_2"><br>
      <input class="left" type="file" accept="image/*" id="File_3"><br>
      <input class="left" type="file" accept="image/*" id="File_4"><br>
    </div>
  </form>
  
  <div id="results" class="right"></div>
  
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <input form="myForm" type="submit" id="submit" value="Serialize Form" />
    <input form="myForm" type="reset" value="Reset Form" onClick="this.form.reset()" />
</body>
```